# onClick not working with <p> element, but working with <button> element

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, onclick

```
export function SignoutButton() {
  return (
    <p onClick={() => signOut({ callbackUrl: "/" })}>
      <IoIosLogOut />
      Logout
    </p>
  );
}
```

I had this function in next.js which was not working I wasted so much time until I changed the function to this

```
export function SignoutButton() {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => signOut({ callbackUrl: "/" })}>
      <IoIosLogOut />
      Logout
    </button>
  );
}
```

Then it started working does anyone know the reason to this?

I am using "use client" at the top I have everything that I am supposed to have I think, let me know if I am missing something

also for extra context this is the code surrounding this

```
<ul className="mt-3 z-[1] p-4 shadow menu menu-sm dropdown-content bg-base-100 rounded-box">
    <li>
        <Link href="/profile">
        <FaRegUser />
        Profile
        </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
        <SignoutButton />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Let me know if you guys need more information

Answer (score 0):

Event handling and behaviors can differ based on the HTML element used, buttons have built-in click handling and are designed for triggering actions, whereas other elements like paragraphs are not primarily meant for interactive actions.

Comment: But onclick normally does work for a p element I don't find anything online tht it says it shouldn't work

Comment: Also, some styling or even the browser used can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: send me a link to this, I know chatgpt is saying this but I can't find anywhere online that is saying this is an issue that can happen